# React Hook called in function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am newbi to react js i was trying to learn by doing project , i was building basic ecom ui with items
i was trying to create a basket to add the item into the cart , but i faced that problem

React Hook "useStateValue" is called in function "product" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function react-hooks/rules-of-hooksmponent or a custom React Hook function

```
import React from 'react';
import "./Product.css"
import { useStateValue } from "./StateProvider";


function product({id,title,image,price,rating}) {
const [{basket},dispatch] = useStateValue();

const addToBasket = () => {
    dispatch({
        type: "ADD_TO_BASKET",
        item:{
            id:id,
            title:title,
            image:image,
            price:price,
            rating:rating
        },
    })
};

return (
    <div className="product">
    <div className="product__info" >
       <p>{title}</p>
      
       <p className="product__price">
       <small>$</small>
       <strong> {price} </strong>
        </p>
        <div className="product__rating"> 
        {Array(rating)
        .fill( )
        .map((_) => ( 
            <p>-</p>
        ))}
        </div>
        </div>
        <img src={image} alt=""/>
        <button  onClick={addToBasket} className="product__button"> Add to basket </button>
    </div>
);
}

   export default product
```

................................

```
import React from 'react';
import "./Product.css"
import { useStateValue } from "./StateProvider";




 function product({id,title,image,price,rating}) 
  {
  const [{basket},dispatch] = useStateValue();

const addToBasket = () => {
    dispatch({
        type: "ADD_TO_BASKET",
        item:{
            id:id,
            title:title,
            image:image,
            price:price,
            rating:rating
        },
    })
};

return (
    <div className="product">
    <div className="product__info" >
       <p>{title}</p>
      
       <p className="product__price">
       <small>$</small>
       <strong> {price} </strong>
        </p>
        <div className="product__rating"> 
        {Array(rating)
        .fill( )
        .map((_) => ( 
            <p>-</p>
        ))}
        </div>
        </div>
        <img src={image} alt=""/>
        <button  onClick={addToBasket} className="product__button"> Add to basket </button>
    </div>
);
}

export default product
```

.....................................

```
import React from 'react';
import Product from "./Product";
import "./Home.css";

function Home() {
    return (
        <div className="home">
            <img class="home__image" src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse4.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.3U6xnN8wOOQ5atG6MO907wHaEK%26pid%3DApi&f=1"/>
      <div className="home__row">
                <Product
                    id="300"
                    title="Argan oil"
                    price={11.96}
                    rating={5}
                    image="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/e6/13/0e/e6130ed7d4820b7eba0a1ba7a631abea.jpg"
              alt=""  />



                <Product
                    id="300"
                    title="Argan oil"
                    price={11.96}
                    rating={5}
                    image="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/ef/c4/01/efc4017b4340dfc35a98ca2235189759.jpg"
                    alt="" />


                <Product
                    id="300"
                    title="Argan oil"
                    price={11.96}
                    rating={5}
                    image="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.byrdie.com%2Fthmb%2F6a2mRHTbEwSWrTOTG1yT5gFDxFs%3D%2F700x700%2Ffilters%3Ano_upscale()%3Amax_bytes(150000)%3Astrip_icc()%2Fcdn.cliqueinc.com__cache__posts__269825__iherb-natural-beauty-products-269825-1539195561186-product.700x0c-6534d2dd4ba1409b84d89684001853df.jpg&f=1&nofb=1"
                    alt="" />


                <Product
                    id="300"
                    title="Argan oil"
                    price={11.96}
                    rating={5}
                    image="https://s3.images-iherb.com/sre/sre01007/r/1.jpg"
                    alt="" />

                <Product
                    id="300"
                    title="Argan oil"
                    price={11.96}
                    rating={5}
                    image="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fi.pinimg.com%2Foriginals%2Fb7%2Fb4%2F72%2Fb7b47228df40d8a2759f30aa778ff31c.jpg&f=1&nofb=1"
                    alt="" />
                <Product
                    id="300"
                    title="Argan oil"
                    price={11.96}
                    rating={5}
                    image="https://s3.images-iherb.com/now/now04920/r/9.jpg"
                    alt="" />
      </div>


       
       

        </div>
    )
}

export default Home;
```

Comment: Try capitalizing the `product` component definition.

Comment: i try it before is not working my dear

Answer (score 0):

I changed two things and error fixed
first in **Product.js** I changed name of function to Product(capitialzing)
second in **reducer.js** I changed ...action.item to action.item

Answer (score 0):

1.change the function product to **Product** in component Product.js that is all and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

its a very simple fix, so the issue is the `useStateValue()` must start with a capital letter. change it to `"UseStateValue()"` in the `stateProvider.js` file and then run it. the compiler will let you know where you have to make the changes and run it. it will solve it

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you're using Context API and creating amazon clone from clever programmer youtube channel.

This error comes when <Home /> component not placed inside <StateProvider> component

Here is my StateProvider.js

```
import React, { useContext, createContext, useReducer } from 'react';

export const StateContext = createContext();

function StateProvider({ reducer, initialState, children}) {
    return (
        <StateContext.Provider value={ useReducer(reducer, initialState) }>
            { children }
        </StateContext.Provider>
    );
}

export const useStateValue = () => useContext(StateContext);
export default StateProvider;
```

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import Header from "./components/Header/Header";
import Home from "./components/Home/Home";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
    return  (
        <StateProvider reducer={Reducer} initialState={initialState} >
            <div className="app">
                <BrowserRouter>
                    <Routes>
                        <Route path="/" element={
                            <>
                                <Header />
                                <Home />
                            </>
                        } />
                    </Routes>
                </BrowserRouter>
            </div>
        </StateProvider>
    );
}

export default App;
```

So kindly check whether the <Home /> component is children of <StateProvider>. Only the child component of StateProvider can access useStateValue() hook.